# PHP framework for creating basic but nice looking websites?

Tags: php

I have been asked to write a basic website for a friend - he wants the very basics, home, about, contact and stuff like that. The site doesnt have to do anything fancy (probably wont even use a db) but he wants it to look 'flash' (not adobe flash!). I could easily knock one up in PHP but my styling skills arent the best so i thought there must be some good framework/cms type downloads that i could use as a base and that provide nice styling features built in. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I would simply use a CMS like WordPress, that has a vast number of very nice-looking themes, both free and paid. (Well, I say, "I would"; in fact, I [did](http://gothick.org.uk); my personal site uses WordPress with an inexpensive paid-for theme...)

Comment: You mean knock one out.  Knock up means to impregnate.

Comment: @tandu It means to impregnate, and *also* to quickly put together (similar to "knock out" and "bash out".) And "knock out" also means to render unconscious. But I'll stop now, because this isn't http://english.stackexchange.com/ :)

Comment: I second the wordpress suggestion: it might be overkill if he just wants a really basic website, but its themes are the best out there for a CMS. Or you could code it up and search for a free template for the graphics, like here http://www.freetemplatesonline.com/ or analogue sites.

Comment: thanks Damien - might have a look at the free templates site and just do the code myself. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Wordpress, it has lots of themes you can implement simply through the admin. 
It also has lots of hooks so if you want to do any custom PHP it is quite simple to use.

www.wordpress.com